# Sync time out protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am writing a test to a definitly angular web app.
now, the web site require basic authentication.
i suspect that because of that it throws this problem.
i tried everything i know and i am realy desperate for an solution.

this is the error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

this is the config.js

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: {defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000},

capabilities:
// {
  // browserName: 'firefox'
// },
{
  browserName: 'chrome'

  }

};
```

this is the spec.js

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

beforeEach(function() {
// browser.get('https://coderbot:coderbot123@alpha.sparkbeyond.com');
browser.get('https://******:******@alpha.spa*****ond.com/#');
});

it('should have a title', function() {
expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Sp****yond');
});

});
```

please help me

Comment: Does your url `https://******:******@alpha.spa*****ond.com/#` work when you open it manually? If not then i guess you cannot bypass the basic authentication. There are other manual ways to bypass basic authentication, one is using a browser plugin to do authenticate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by making this addition

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Comment: Please, add more context to the answer. Where did you put the addition?